# Excel 2016 VBA - error 91 when assigning sheet to array of sheets using for each sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Pretty much as the title says. I keep getting runtime error 91 when it gets to the specified lines.

it's probably something obvious, but i'm not seeing it. any help would be appreciated. here's my (abbreviated) code:

```
Sub wat()
    Dim EHSBook As Workbook
    Dim Err as Boolean

    Dim sheetRecord As Worksheet
    Dim sheetAmList(7) As Worksheet
    Dim sheetPmList(7) As Worksheet
    Dim sheetAmListCnt As Integer
    Dim sheetPmListCnt As Integer

    sheetAmListCnt = 1
    sheetPmListCnt = 1

    Call OpenEhsFile(EHSBook, Err)
    If Err = True Then Exit Sub

    'get which sheets we need to total up
    For Each sheetRecord In EHSBook.Sheets
        If IsDate(sheetRecord.Cells(1, 3).Value) Then
            If Right(sheetRecord.name, 4) = "(AM)" Then
                ' next line throws error 91
                sheetAmList(sheetAmListCnt) = sheetRecord
                sheetAmListCnt = sheetAmListCnt + 1
            ElseIf Right(sheetRecord.name, 4) = "(PM)" Then
                ' next line throws error 91
                sheetPmList(sheetPmListCnt) = sheetRecord
                sheetPmListCnt = sheetPmListCnt + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next sheetRecord
End Sub
```

I Tried: I made sure I was declaring my arrays properly and that the EHSBook was being assigned properly.

I Expected: I expect the code to add the records(sheets) i need to process to either array based on if it's the AM or PM record.

I Get: I get a pop up that says Run-Time Error: '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

The array i'm saving to is declared in the same Sub, the counter sheetAmListCnt is assigned immediately before the For Each, and For Each should be using the reference so should not need a With... so i'm confused.

Comment: @braX: good to know, i was unaware that Sheets was not the same as Worksheets. However, the issue persists when i use Worksheets as well.

Comment: What is the significance of 7? The first element is usually 0, not 1. To remove confusion, declare the arrays in the following way: `Dim sheetAmList() As Worksheet: ReDim sheetAmList(1 To 7)`. You probably want to use the *Set* keyword e.g. `Set sheetAmList(sheetAmListCnt) = sheetRecord`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 7 is the maximum possible sheets for either AM or PM that can be added to the EHSBook. (aka, the full week) There will never be more than 7 PM records and 7 AM records. (I will handle exceptions like this once the core functionality of the code is implemented)

Comment: @VBasic2008 Just saw your edit. yeah, I was missing the Set keyword. I feel kinda dumb now lol

Comment: Please share the `OpenEhsFile` procedure so we can draw some additional conclusions i.e. you haven't declared `Err`. It's easier to fix issues at the beginning. Are you sure that collections wouldn't be better than arrays in this case? Share what you plan to do with those arrays.

Comment: @VBasic2008: I can't share the OpenEhsFile code as it includes a lot of private information. In general, it tries to guess the correct path based on the current date and asks the user to verify if the guessed path is accurate, and allows the user to specify the path if it's incorrect. it then checks for already-open files with that path and name, and if it's not already open, opens the file. There is not an issue in this function, as I have been using it for over two years for various processes.

i plan to iterate through each record several times to compare various things in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Returning Objects in Data Structures

- To make the arrays one-based, you define them dynamically and resize them using the `To` keyword.
- If your variable is declared `As Worksheet` then loop over the `Worksheets` (not `Sheets`) collection.
- If you can help it, you don't want to look in cells of irrelevant worksheets (see the implementation in the *Improvement*).
- When assigning an object to an element of an array, you need to use the `Set` keyword.

**A Quick Fix (Array)**

```vb
Sub watQF()
    
    ' Open the workbook.
    Dim EHSBook As Workbook ' : Set EHSBook = ThisWorkbook
    
    Call OpenEhsFile(EHSBook, Err)
    If Err = True Then Exit Sub

    Dim sheetRecord As Worksheet
    Dim sheetAmList() As Worksheet: ReDim sheetAmList(1 To 7) ' ***
    Dim sheetPmList() As Worksheet: ReDim sheetPmList(1 To 7) ' ***
    Dim sheetAmListCnt As Long ' ***
    Dim sheetPmListCnt As Long ' ***

    'get which sheets we need to total up
    For Each sheetRecord In EHSBook.Worksheets ' ***
        If IsDate(sheetRecord.Range("C1").Value) Then ' ***
            If Right(sheetRecord.Name, 4) = "(AM)" Then
                sheetAmListCnt = sheetAmListCnt + 1
                Set sheetAmList(sheetAmListCnt) = sheetRecord ' ***
            ElseIf Right(sheetRecord.Name, 4) = "(PM)" Then
                sheetPmListCnt = sheetPmListCnt + 1
                Set sheetPmList(sheetPmListCnt) = sheetRecord ' ***
            End If
        End If
    Next sheetRecord
    
    ' Print the sheet names by 'AM/PM'.
    
    Dim sheet As Variant ' *** !!!
    
    Debug.Print "Listing AM-sheets (Array)"
    For Each sheet In sheetAmList
        If Not sheet Is Nothing Then ' *** !!!
            Debug.Print sheet.Name
        End If
    Next sheet

    Debug.Print "Listing PM-sheets (Array)"
    For Each sheet In sheetAmList
        If Not sheet Is Nothing Then ' *** !!!
            Debug.Print sheet.Name
        End If
    Next sheet

End Sub
```

Results:

The list is short due to case insensitivity. See how it is handled in the *Improvement*.

```
Listing AM-sheets (Array)
Mon(AM)
Listing PM-sheets (Array)
```

[image]

**An Improvement (Collection)**

Why?

- You don't need to predetermine the size i.e. you just `.Add`.
- You don't use the `Set` keyword.
- You can use the appropriate object variable to loop through its items.
- You don't have to check if an element contains an object: it wouldn't exist if it doesn't.
- Note that using the *Dictionary* object, 'an improved collection', could add even more flexibility.

```vb
Sub wat()
    
    ' Open the workbook.
    Dim EHSBook As Workbook ' : Set EHSBook = ThisWorkbook

    Call OpenEhsFile(EHSBook, Err)
    If Err = True Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Define two collections to hold the worksheets to total up.
    Dim amList As Collection: Set amList = New Collection
    Dim pmList As Collection: Set pmList = New Collection
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsName As String, Position As Long
    
    ' Add the worksheets whose names end with '(AM)' or '(PM)'
    ' to the associated collections i.e. 'amList' or 'pmList' respectively.
    For Each ws In EHSBook.Worksheets
        wsName = ws.Name
        Position = Len(wsName) - 3 ' -3 = -4 + 1
        Select Case True
            Case InStrRev(wsName, "(AM)", , vbTextCompare) = Position
                amList.Add ws
            Case InStrRev(wsName, "(PM)", , vbTextCompare) = Position
                pmList.Add ws
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next ws
     
    ' Print the sheet names by 'AM/PM'.
     
    Debug.Print "Listing AM-sheets (Collection)"
    For Each ws In amList
        Debug.Print vbTab & ws.Name
    Next ws
    
    Debug.Print "Listing PM-sheets (Collection)"
    For Each ws In pmList
        Debug.Print vbTab & ws.Name
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Results:

```
Listing AM-sheets (Collection)
    Mon(AM)
    Tue(am)
Listing PM-sheets (Collection)
    Mon(pm)
    Tue(Pm)
```

Comment: a few questions on these:
-Why do you need to ReDim after you Dim? that seems redundant.
-What's the difference between Cells(1,3) and Range("C1")? i will never be checking a range with this.
-Collections seem like all around better arrays, so is it a good idea to just always use collections?